# wsl.exe always appears multiple times in eclipse local terminal custom entries

Tags: eclipse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using eclipse 2021-06 on a windows 10 PC, when I open a local terminal, it always displays  multiple rows for the wsl.exe terminal, with names like this...

[image]

Even when I go to the eclipse Window -> Preferences -> Terminal -> Local Terminal settings and delete these custom entries, they still continue to appear in the list.

How can I permanently delete these local terminal entries from eclipse?

Comment: Your Eclipse is outdated. Please upgrade and show a screenshot of what you are talking about.

Comment: added screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer:*

Upgrading to the latest Eclipse release should fix the issue.

*More detail:*

I'm going to take an educated guess here without (apologies) attempting to reproduce it myself.  As @howlger mentioned in the comments, the 2021-06 release is a bit outdated.

When it was released, there were essentially two states for WSL:

- If the WSL feature was not enabled in Windows, then there was no `wsl.exe` binary on the system.
- When the WSL feature was enabled, the `wsl.exe` command became available.

So Eclipse is likely checking for the existing of `wsl.exe` and running the `wsl -l -q` command to get a list of distributions.

However, in both the Windows 21H2 release and Windows 11, the WSL behavior has changed.  `wsl.exe` *always* exists, but operates in two states:

- When WSL is not enabled, `wsl.exe` is simply a tool that enables/installs it (via `wsl --install`).  If executed with any other arguments (like `wsl -l -q`, as Eclipse probably is), then it returns the help.  This is what you are seeing - Eclipse is erroneously parsing the *help* output and believing that it is a list of distributions.
- When WSL *is* enabled, `wsl.exe` becomes the actually CLI interface to WSL.

As @howlger also points out in the comments to this answer, the [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575159) was known and has been fixed.

If for some strange reason you can't upgrade, you can almost certainly stop the problem from occurring by enabling WSL in *Turn Windows Features On or Off*.  If you don't install any distributions, then `wsl -l -q` should return an empty list for Eclipse.

If upgrading to the latest Eclipse doesn't work, which I think would be unlikely, then you may be facing a different issue that you might need to report to the Eclipse team.

Comment: I remember the issue showing elements named _"Copyright (c), ..."_ etc. quite some time ago, but I can't see it in recent Eclipse. Please do not suggest to report issues from outdated and no longer maintained versions. Make sure also not to report duplicates.

Comment: That issue existed only in 2021-06 containing Eclipse CDT 10.3 providing the Terminal feature. One version later (2021-09 with CDT 10.4 which is outdated now for a long time too) the issue was fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=575159

Comment: @howlger Please re-read my post closely - We're saying the same thing!  Note that I said that it should be fixed in the latest release.  I only recommended that the bug report be filed if the user had already upgraded to the latest release (as I suggested as my answer) and it still wasn't fixed.  Also, I did search the open bug list before suggesting that -- Apparently the default search doesn't return closed bugs, but if the latest release didn't fix it for the user, then it wouldn't be a duplicate, since there is no open issue on that topic.

Comment: Feel free to add the link of the bug report and to update your answer that it was fixed long time ago. I did not say that your answer was wrong, I'm just concerned that open source projects are wasting their time with bug reports from people who miss to update.

Comment: I've had issues updating to later version when using some plugins, which is why I am using 2021-06.

Comment: @httPants Makes sense.  Did you try enabling WSL?  Just turning on the feature in *"Turn Windows Features on or off"* should do the trick.  It doesn't use any extra memory really to just have it enabled, and it should then cause Eclipse to detect it properly.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - you were 100% correct.  I enabled the windows subsystem for linux feature.  The wsl.exe terminal entries were still there, but this time when I deleted them from eclipse and restarted eclipse, they no longer re-appeared.

Comment: @httPants Fix the problems with these plugins instead of sticking with an outdated Eclipse (maybe [running Eclipse with Java 11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) instead of a higher Java version does the trick). Only updating [TM Terminal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tm-terminal) should also be possible.